# Wrap.builder like in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use **Wrap** on large amount of objects.

I tried to just map all object to **children** but it cause *serious performance issue*.

I want some alternative way to build only currently displayed widgets but with style of **Wrap**.

Some code:

```dart
Wrap(
  children: list.map(createCardFromData), // List contains 20'000 items
);
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you show us some code!

Comment: Something like this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

Comment: @Andrija yes, but I want them to wrap.

Comment: Can you tell if the items are of various height/width? If not, do you have any sketch of how it would look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really good example flutter is missing in my opinion.

This is also something which is being discussed on Flutter's repo
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97544

Unfortunately, it will take some time for it to be in stable release. For the time being, I would suggest to paginate the data into chunks of maybe 100 items. There are other ways as well which might involve a lot of calculations.  Meanwhile, I (or maybe some other person) could try to come up with a efficient solution and maybe contribute to the Flutter.

After some fiddling, I could build sample app per your requirement.

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: scrollable_wrap
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.4 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  random_avatar: ^0.0.7
  random_words: ^1.0.2
  dynamic_layouts:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:flutter/packages.git
      path: packages/dynamic_layouts

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:dynamic_layouts/dynamic_layouts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:random_avatar/random_avatar.dart';
import 'package:random_words/random_words.dart';

class Item {
  final String label;
  final String avatar;

  Item(this.label) : avatar = randomAvatarString(label);
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scrollable Wrap',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Item> data = [];

  int n = 100000;

  void init() async {
    data = generateNoun().take(n).map((e) => Item(e.asString)).toList();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Scrollable Wrap'),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
        DynamicSliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithWrapping(
            mainAxisSpacing: 0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 0,
            childCrossAxisExtent: double.infinity,
            childMainAxisExtent: double.infinity,
          ),
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              if (kDebugMode) {
                print('build called for $index');
              }
              final item = data[index];
              return Chip(
                key: ValueKey(item),
                label: Text('$index ${item.label}'),
                avatar: SvgPicture.string(item.avatar),
              );
            },
            childCount: data.length,
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Output
[image: Output]

Please use `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety` as one of the library is not null-safe. Also, you might find lag as lots of svgs are being processed on scroll. It might not happen in production.

Comment: I have just implemented this into my app, it looks perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this many items loaded at once? You're probably using a scroll view anyway, so the user only initially sees a small batch of items rather than all of them, until they actually scroll for more. What you're looking for is **lazy loading**, maybe combined with a technique like infinite scroll.

Try a `ListView` (specifically, `ListView.builder`) where each item contains a `Wrap` widget (say, each 10 items - but you may want to experiment with this number until you see a balance between performance and visual appeal).

Or, alternatively, you may code your own `Wrap` that does loading lazily and reuses its views, so that it only loads and displays a couple of its children as needed, not thousands at once.

Comment: Wont it be discontinuous?
I want to avoid making my code (maybe if no one answer I will have to).

Comment: While it might look uglier than a regular `Wrap`, I believe that a clever solution (I suggested a primitive trial-and-error approach above) to calculate the amount of `Wrap` children per each list item can mask this quite well. 

Or, while you're at it, maybe a `GridView.builder` will better serve your needs?

Comment: Yes, I think `GridView.builder` will be best of not actual `Wrap` solution. And `ListView.Builder` can't be used cause children are different size and with amount of children it's not really possible to pick good enough chunk size.

Answer (score 1):

If your items are fixed width you could try something like this:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

typedef ValueWidgetBuilder<T> = Widget Function(T value);

class WrapBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final double itemWidth;
  final List items;
  final ValueWidgetBuilder itemBuilder;

  const WrapBuilder(
      {Key? key,
      required this.itemWidth,
      required this.items,
      required this.itemBuilder})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      var cardsPerRow = max(1, constraints.maxWidth ~/ itemWidth);
      return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            controller: ScrollController(),
            itemCount: (items.length / cardsPerRow).ceil(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              var rowItems = items.sublist(cardsPerRow * index,
                  min(cardsPerRow * (index + 1), items.length));
              return Row(children: [
                for (final item in rowItems)
                  SizedBox(
                      width: itemWidth,
                      child: itemBuilder(item))
              ]);
            },
          );
    });
  }
}
```

And then use like

```
WrapBuilder(
    itemWidth: 100, //example
    items: list,
    itemBuilder: createCardFromData);
```

Comment: sadly they are not. :(